# When should I prefer property over method?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

When should I prefer property over method ? Because the following code is more readable when I use property.

```
string agency = base.GetAgencyDetails();

string agency = base.Agency; //I could write same logic in getter of the property.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, I'd follow the [MSDN Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229054.aspx) on this.

> In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data. Properties are meant to be used like fields, meaning that properties should not be computationally complex or produce side effects. When it does not violate the following guidelines, consider using a property, rather than a method, because less experienced developers find properties easier to use.

It makes perfect sense if you think about it, a method would be more suited to something that would potentially *alter* data in some way, and a property is perfect for when you're retrieving some data and caching it.

If you're using an explicitly backed property, you could even combine the two in the case of a transform:

```
private ObjType _myObjWithStringification;
private string _stringRepOfData;

public string StringRepresentation
{
    get {
        if (_stringRepOfData == null) {
            _stringRepOfData = _myObjWithStringification.ToString();
        }
        return _stringRepOfData;
    }
}
```

---

Re: Your maintainability comment, I'm not sure it's very much valid. If you were to hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to the declaration of the property you're using, you'll go straight to the `get`ter anyway, just like you'd go to the method body if you used a method.

I'm not sure it's safe to assume that a property *isn't* going to have any custom retrieval logic.

Comment: Ask yourself this, a year from now, if there is a problem with this logic, will I spend an hour troubleshooting before realizing that I tucked this code away in the property itself. Code in properties has a tendency to be hidden and you forget it's in there. (sorry, probably should have put this on the OP)

Comment: I gave you a +1, but to my own comment, most people skip over properties when debuggins. If you actually step into all properties during debugging, then you are more thorough than most people.

Comment: If you're debugging an issue, it only helps to be thorough. I'm not sure why you'd treat a property any different from a method, I generally always use Step Into when debugging, if I ended up in something irrelevant, I can just as quickly step back out.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to write a lot of logic, then method, not property.

If you do a method call in the logic, then again method, not property.

Answer (score 0):

Ref from [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data. Properties are meant to be used like fields, meaning that properties should not be computationally complex or produce side effects. When it does not violate the following guidelines, consider using a property, rather than a method, because less experienced developers find properties easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

A property is simply a set of wrapper method (get/set) around a backing field.

The prefered way is to use a property so your external contract doesn't change, however you could later add additional logic or validations to the property methods.

Also makes the code cleaner as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

At their core properties are meant to be a wrapper over field access and provide unification between normal and calculated fields.  Any operation which is akin to a field access should be represented as a property when possible.

That's not an absolute rule, it's a guideline.  It's hard to draw up definitive rules for what should be a property over a method.  However the reverse is not true; it is very clear when a method should be preferred over a property.

- The operation has a visible side effect on the type.  For example if it visibly mutates any state in the object the operation should never be a property.
- Long running operations including expensive operations should never be properties